# How to solve _ContiguousArrayStorage<UIButton> memory leak in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uibutton

I am new to Leak Instrument and start learning how to fix memory leak. I have the following code:

```
class InputButtonsContainerView: UIView {

var hexButtons = [UIButton]()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    //Configure buttons
    for view in subviews {
        for btn in view.subviews where btn is UIButton {
            let button = btn as! UIButton
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            button.layer.cornerRadius = SizeAdaptation.shared.inputButtonCornerRadius
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: SizeAdaptation.shared.inputButtonFontSize)
            if button.tag > 9 && button.tag < 16 {
                hexButtons.append(button)
            }
        }
    }
    defer{
        inputMode = .dec
    }
}

var inputMode = MakerInputMode.dec {
    didSet{
        switch inputMode {
        case .dec:
            for btn in hexButtons {
                btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
                btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
            }
        case .hex:
            for btn in hexButtons {
                btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In AddColorViewController class, there is an IBOutlet object of InputButtonsContainerView:

```
class AddColorViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var inputButtonsContainerView: InputButtonsContainerView!
    ....
}
```

And Leak Instrument show there is a leak in init function:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
It seems that the `UIButton` array was released twice and cause the reference count to be -1. Does anyone know how to fix this ? Thank you.